# Data is displayed only momentarily as you scroll down the screen [Flutter RefreshIndicator]

Tags: flutter

I'm flutter beginer. Please meet you. I study flutter and firebase Auth and CRUD from
this gentlemans app

https://github.com/fesaworld/flutter_firebase_auth_crud_firestore/blob/master/lib/screen/mainpage/mainpage_view.dart

I can succesfuly user login and post data. However. At mainpage data is Data is displayed only momentarily as you scroll down the screen.

I checked at desktop emulater also. At this time I don't see any data.

I tryed to adjust code like remove RefreshIndicator fucntion. but it doesn't work.
Could someone teach me what is wrong?

Here is my current code.

`

```
 class MainpageView extends StatelessWidget {
   const MainpageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return GetBuilder<MainpageController>(
        init: MainpageController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return Scaffold(
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                controller.createDataDialog(uuid: controller.uuid!);
              },
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(
                '1104-2023',
                style: title,
              ),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: SafeArea(
                child: SizedBox(
                    height: Get.height,
                    width: Get.width,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(
                          parent: BouncingScrollPhysics()),
                      child: Column(children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                            stream: controller.notesCollection
                                 ?.where('uuid', isEqualTo: controller.uuid)
                                .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
                                .snapshots(),
                            builder: (_, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                return Column(
                                  children: snapshot.data!.docs
                                      .map((e) => NotesCardWidget(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              controller.updateDataDialog(
                                                id: e.id,
                                                uuid: (e.data()
                                                    as dynamic)['uuid'],
                                                title: (e.data()
                                                    as dynamic)['title'],
                                                subTitle: (e.data()
                                                   as dynamic)['body'],
                                              );
                                            },
                                            titleNote:
                                                (e.data() as dynamic)['title'],
                                            subTitleNote:
                                                (e.data() as dynamic)['body'],
                                           ))
                                       .toList(),
                                );
                              } else {
                                return const Column(
                                  children: [
                                    CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                      Text('Loading!!!'),
                                  ],
                                );
                              }
                            }),
                      ]),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
         );
        });
  }
 }
`
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. So I better use getx for this.